# convert database of ruby on rails app from sql server to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

i had clone a ruby on rails app with `sql server`, with some code like :

```
# Gemfile
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.2.0'
```

and `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlserver
  azure: true

development: &development
  <<: *default
  host:     <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASS'] %>

development_vehicle: &development_vehicle
  <<: *default
  host:     <%= ENV['DATABASE_VEHICLE_HOST'] || ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_VEHICLE_NAME'] || ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_VEHICLE_USER'] || ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_VEHICLE_PASS'] || ENV['DATABASE_PASS'] %>

development_aspnet: &development_aspnet
  <<: *default
  host:     <%= ENV['DATABASE_ASPNETDB_HOST'] || ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_ASPNETDB_NAME'] || ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_ASPNETDB_USER'] || ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_ASPNETDB_PASS'] || ENV['DATABASE_PASS'] %>
```

`db` folder like :

[image]

but my local use `mysql`, so i want to use `mysql` instead to `sql server` to buil this app

can you help me to convert it ?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Gemfile

```
# gem 'tiny_tds'
# gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'mysql2'
```

## config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username : root #mysql username
  password : root #mysql password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name
```

Comment: There is no need to add the host in mysql?

Comment: i tried to do like this, i can create database with `rake db:create`, and get error when migration by `rake db:migration`:
`NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter`,

do we need another way to do ?

Comment: i still get the same error, can you check my updated question to see the `db` folder. It's difference with folder of mysql `db/migrate`. is it reason?

Comment: rename folder name sqls to migrate OR try to run commad rake db:sqls

Comment: it is still not ok, maybe because inside `sqls` folder, i have set of `.sql` file, not `.rb` file like `migrate` folder

Comment: yes inside migrate folder all file extension be .rb

Answer (score 0):

Add mysql2 gem and remove other connection gem required for sql server.

```
# Gemfile
# gem 'tiny_tds'
# gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'mysql2'
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development: &development
  <<: *default
  host:     yourhostfordevelopement # commonly localhost
  database: yourdb # for development
  username: dbusername # commonly root
  password: dbpasseord # password you configured

development_vehicle: &development_vehicle
  <<: *default
  host:     yourhostfordevelopement # commonly localhost
  database: yourdb # for development_vehicle
  username: dbusername # commonly root
  password: dbpasseord # password you configured

development_aspnet: &development_aspnet
  <<: *default
  host:     yourhostfordevelopement # commonly localhost
  database: yourdb # for development_aspnet
  username: dbusername # commonly root
  password: dbpasseord # password you configured
```

Comment: many thanks, i created database with `rake db:create`, can you help me to migrate database with `db` folder like my updated question ?